# I have table returned by select, how to calculate sum of field2, where f1 is similar?

Tags: mysql

```
f1              f2
guest           100
tester          0
user            200
user            200
```

desired result:

```
f1              f2
guest           100
user            400
tester          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT f1, SUM(f2)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY f1
```

Comment: this returns SUM of all f2 from full table

Comment: @Andrew: It shouldn't. The `GROUP BY` clause means that you should get a separate sum for each distinct value in the `f1` column.